# java JSON string formatting with regular expression

Tags: java, json, regex

For a given plain JSON data do the following formatting:

1. replace all the special characters in **key** with underscore
2. remove the **key** double quote
3. replace the : with =

**Example:**

JSON Data:  {"no/me": "139.82", "gc.pp": "\u0000\u000", ...}

After formatting:  no_me="139.82", gc_pp="\u0000\u000"

Is it possible with a regular expression? or any other single command execution?

Comment: Please, specify if input can have nested structures (such arrays) or if it is as simple as the given input. Also, can you specify what are 'special characters'? Any non-A-Z0-9 maybe?

Comment: What's the drive to put this into a single command?  Is it something you must do from the command line quite often? I'd suggest you just write a little parser in a method and call it.. you have a single line without the complexity of a bunch of regex garbage in-line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

A single regex for the whole changes may be overkill. I think you could code something *similar* to this:

(NOTE: Since i do not code in java, my example is in javascript, just to get you the idea of it)

```js
var json_data = '{"no/me": "139.82", "gc.pp": "0000000", "foo":"bar"}';
console.log(json_data);
var data = JSON.parse(json_data);
var out = '';
for (var x in data) {
  var clean_x = x.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_");
  if (out != '') out += ', ';
  out += clean_x + '="' + data[x] + '"';
}
console.log(out);
```

Basically you loop through the keys and clean them (remove not-wanted characters), with the new key and the original value you create a new string with the format you like.

**Important**: Bear in mind overlapping ids. For example, both `no/me` and `no#me` will overlap into same id `no_me`. this may not be important since your are not outputting a JSON after all. I tell you just in case.

Comment: This is Javascript, the OP is asking a Java question.

Comment: Added a warning to OP. Anybody feel free to implement something similar in java :-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done Java in a long time, but I think you need something like this.
I'm assuming you mean 'all Non-Word characters' by `specialchars` here.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String JsonData = '{"no/me": "139.82", "gc.pp": "\u0000\u000", ...}';

// remove { and }
JsonData = JsonData.substring(0, JsonData.length() - 1);
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]+\")\\s*:");                 // find the keys, including quotes and colon
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(JsonData);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        String temp = regexMatcher.group(1);                              // "no/me": 
        String key = regexMatcher.group(2).replaceAll("\\W", "_") + "=";  // no_me=
        JsonData.replaceAll(temp, key);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // regex has syntax error
}

System.out.println(JsonData);
```